# repair hole in hardwood floor near garage door

Tags: hardwood-floor, hole

One weekend after a gathering, I noticed that there was a hole in my hardwood floor. The hole is about half an inch in  depth and about the size of penny, maybe a bit larger. I know sometimes hardwood has pin knots, but this looks to be caused by a heavy step of a woman's high-heeled shoe.

What's the best way to fix this without having to tear up the floor?

[image]

Comment: I think you have more to worry about than repairing the hole. If you have a craw space, go under the house and inspect the sub floor. From the picture, it seems you have some rot going on. For someones high heel to collapse your floor, most of the hardwood must be rotted and the sub floor gone in that place.

Comment: If indeed the floor is sound and this was just a factory void under the laminate, just plug it with a good solvent base wood putty that comes close in color. I would not go chopping up that floor for a penny sized hole.

Comment: How new?  There may be a warranty claim here.

Comment: @diceless well, I checked and there's no rot. I don't have a crawlspace. This is is the first floor, I have a basement, and there's no issues underneat there at all. The wood around the hole is pretty dry and actually sturdy. It's actually pretty hard to "make the hole larger" as the wood seems pretty solid around

Comment: @Bryce The house was built I believe around 2006-2007. We're the original owners. How long are hardwood floor warranties for? Is the hardwood manufacturer liable or is it the builder?

Comment: @CesarDV ten plus years is a normal warranty for such a floor.  Note: it may be less hassle just to fill this hole rather than complain.  As others have said this is not "normal".

Comment: The only reason I brought that up is because it looks like a small collapse in the floor.  For that to happen, the floor had to be missing a lot of wood and only the top finish about 1/4 of a inch thick (at the thickest).  Since the sub floor looks good (sorry for assuming craw space, where I live that's the best people have) you can assume a defective board was used.  If you have extra planks search google for "how to replace one hardwood board"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solid healthy piece of oak would never collapse like that. You need to figure out what is going on before you fix it. Look at the underside if you can, break away any of the edges of the hole that come out easily (preferably without getting into the surrounding pieces) and try to figure out what you're dealing with. Look hard for moisture or evidence of insects. If you find anything suspicious, those problems *must* be dealt with first.

If ,however, the hole is pretty localized and the rest of the floor feels dry and solid, you can reasonably assume that it was an isolated defect in that piece and proceed with a patch. Here's a pretty decent tutorial on patching hardwood flooring:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ez0GSSVuTyk

Good Luck!

Comment: hmm well, like I mentioned in the comments above, the floor around there seems fine (no insects, etc) and pretty dry and sturdy. Maybe this was a manufacturing defect in the wood? There was a hollow areas and by some bad luck a high-heel shoe just happened to put pressure and break the thinner wood surface there?

Comment: Yeah it's not inconceivable that it was just a weird spot. Was Lana Kane clomping around your house?:)

Comment: Lana Kane? I wish lol